# Ajax Calender Extender format ? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in web application, [asp.net] i place the ajax clander extender and change the date format to dd-MM-yyy, at the time of inserting date in database it is giving error date format is not correect.

```
    Date dt= ConvertTodate(txtdate.tex);
```

This is my code , can you help me.

Comment: this is not obvious that you database need a different format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
string[] datePart txtdate.text.split('-')

DateTime dt = new datetime(datepart[2],datepart[1],datapart[0]);
```